# Vue.js - How to pass down props to grandchildren

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

I have the following App structure

```
RegistrationView (holds the data logic like get, post)
 - RegistrationForm (holds the form)
 -- Registration Radio Component (radio buttons rendered on delivered data from view)
```

and I would like to be able to pass down data from view to radios Component as props to be rendered and interact with parent form component. Is this  possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [dependency injection](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Dependency-Injection) in this case :

in view :

```
provide: function () {
  return {
    prop1: this.someData,
    someMethod:this.someMethod
  }
},
data(){
  return{
    someData:'some data'
  }
},
methods:{
    someMethod(){
       this.someData='another data'
    }
}
```

in radios component :

```
inject: ['someData','someMethod']
```

and use it like `this.someData` and you could trigger `this.someMethod()` and it will change the data in grandparent component.