# How can I $emit on grandchildren in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

My components have multi-level:

```
Class A > Class B > Class C > contain <button/>
```

I want to know how to pass down the `updateTest` in `Class A` as my onClick function in button in `Class C`

**Update 1**

ClassA.vue

```
<template>
  <ClassB @update-test="updateTest" />
</template>

<script>
import ClassB from './ClassB';
  components: {
    ClassB,
  },
  methods: {
    updateTest(name, age) {
      console.log(name)
      console.log(age)     
    },
  }
</script>
```

ClassB.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ClassC
      @update-test="$emit('update-test')"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ClassC from "./ClassC";

export default {
  name: "ClassB",
  components: {
    ClassC,
  },
};
</script>
```

ClassC.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button
      @click="$emit('update-test', 'Tom', '19')"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "ClassC"
};
</script>
```

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim please check my update

Comment: is `update-test` emitted from classA?

Comment: Instead of emitting I suggest you use provide/inject.  Provide a function from the parent and call that function in your children/grandchildren.

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim yes, I updated the code above again, please check

Comment: is this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63550379/8172857 helpful?

Comment: where do emit `update-test` in ClassB?

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim I need to pass `update-test` to `ClassC` and pass to its element `button`, but I don't know how to pass it

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim I provided all Class above. please check

Comment: in classB you could do `<ClassC   @update-test="(name,age)=>$emit('update-test',name,age)"` but It's a bad solution, for that I recommend the provide/inject pattern https://stackoverflow.com/a/63550379/8172857

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event bus` to emit and receive events on complex hierarchical components.

FYI:

- vue2 approach: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-global-event-bus
- vue3 approach: https://github.com/developit/mitt

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in several ways:

- use a global event bus ( not recommended by the Vue Community). Or as Tino suggested, you may [use an external library](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#event-bus).
- go through a two step process, capture event in Class B, then emit an event from B, to capture in Class A.
- Use VUEX to set the state of your Class C states. For example "testUpdated = true.

Comment: Or number 4 as suggested in the [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/events-api.html#event-bus): use an external library implementing the event emitter interface

Comment: If you need to access the data "name: 'Tom', Age: 19" object, then you would do the following:
In Class B, create a method such that ... @update-test="myMethod(object)" 
then in your method ... this.$emit('update-test2', object)

Answer (score 0):

In the component `ClassA` pass the method `updateTest` using provide option:

ClassA:

```
<template>
  <ClassB  />
</template>

<script>
import ClassB from './ClassB';
export default{
  components: {
    ClassB,
  },
  methods: {
    updateTest(name, age) {
      console.log(name)
      console.log(age)     
    },
 
  },
provide: function () {
  return {
  
    updateTest:this.updateTest
  }
},
}
</script>
```

**ClassC** : inject the method from the classA in order to run it when you click on the button

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button
      @click="updateTest('Tom', '19')"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "ClassC",
  inject: ['updateTest']
};
</script>
```